# Is there a fullscreen Terminal app that is faster than iTerm?

Tags: terminal

I am used to using the Terminal in full screen on Ubuntu. On Apple, the native Terminal app doesn't do full screen, and iTerm, which does, is very, very slow when you use a multiplexer like tmux in the Terminal. I'm using iTerm 0.10.

Does anyone know of an OS X Terminal program that can go full screen and that is responsive when running tmux?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try [iTerm2](http://www.iterm2.com). It's supposed to be significantly faster than iTerm, but since I've never used the first version, I can't say for myself.

I have no complaints about it, that's for sure.

Answer (score 4):

Interestingly, at Apple's special event on June 6, 2011, one of the items in the additional features slides when they were talking about Lion was "Full screen terminal."

[image: Additional Lion features]

So just waiting until next month will probably get you want you want as part of the system software.

Comment: Nice catch! :-)

Comment: Here's an article on Lion's new Terminal. http://osxdaily.com/2011/05/23/terminal-in-mac-os-x-lion-gets-full-screen-mode-eye-candy/